# Why the image is not getting resize in following scenario?

Tags: html, css, tooltip, image-resizing

I've a set of three horizontal images. Upon hovering each of these images I'm showing tool-tip image. But the issue I'm facing is I'm not able to resize the image. If I go for reducing the height and width of the tool-tip image only the part of image displays. Actually the whole image should be displayed on hover. But it's not happening. Can someone please help me in this regard?

Following is **HTML** code:

```
<table style="width:100%" id="thumbs">
                      <tr>
                        <td><span style="cursor:pointer" id="tooltip1"><img id="img1" width="80" height="80" src="http://54.174.50.242/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/layout/OpenIcon.png"/></span></td> 
                        <td><span style="cursor:pointer" id="tooltip2"><img id="img2" width="80" height="80" src="http://54.174.50.242/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/layout/ColsedIcon.png"/></span> </td>
                        <td><span style="cursor:pointer" id="tooltip3"><img id="img3" width="80" height="80" src="http://54.174.50.242/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/layout/SecretIcon.png"/></span> </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
```

**CSS** code :

```
tr span {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
tr span:hover {
    z-index: 1;
}
tr span:hover:after {
    content:"";
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/273/274/');
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 273px;
    height: 274px;
}
```

Can someone please help me in this regard?

JS Fiddle link is as follows: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/891tvx7d/7/)**

Comment: Looks fine to me in the fiddle

Comment: Yh looks fine for me to in the fiddle. Could you explain more clearly what you wish to happend maby by pictures/screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

```
tr span:hover:after {
    content:"";
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/273/279/');
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

this way you can reduce the size of tool-tip and still display the whole image.

Comment: Doesn't this still crop the image if the width and height are not equal to the size of the image?

Comment: no it doesn't. `background-size:cover;` forces the background image to fit.

Comment: Set the width to 50px and height to 100px and you will see that there is a section missing. `From W3: cover Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area.`

Comment: sorry, but didn't that work? whats the problem with this solution?

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

```
tr span:hover:after {
content:"";
background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/273/274/');
background-size:contain; 
position: absolute;
top:50%;
left: 50%;
width: 273px;
height: 274px;
}
```

Comment: This does `contain` the image size, maybe add `background-repeat: no-repeat`?